# Gradient Projection Method - Find a Cauchy point

Tags: optimization, vector-analysis, projection, quadratic-programming

I am finding a Cauchy point to minimize a quadratic problem using gradient projection method. And I get a trouble reading this equation.

$x(t) = x(t_{j−1}) + ∆t*p_{j−1}$ where $∆t=t_{j}-t_{j-1}$.

For example let us say that $t_{j-1}=0.0024$. Then what does $x(t_{j−1})=x(0.0024)$ mean and how do I compute it?